# I want to be cv direct downloaded by clicking download button

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

when I click on download resume button it directs the pdf instead of direct download. I want to direct download the resume by clicking the download button.

```
<div class="text-center m-top-50">
    <a class="btn line-btn-dark btn-icon btn-radius" href="1.pdf" title=""<i class="fa fa-download" download></i> Download Resume</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the download attribute for the `<a>` element.

```
<a class="btn line-btn-dark btn-icon btn-radius" href="1.pdf" title="" download>
```

Refer https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_download_link.asp